# Input to reshape is a tensor with 4096 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 6400. (Having problem with shapes)

Tags: tensorflow, data-science-model, reshape

I am trying to make  a caption generator model.
**(Having problem with shapes)**
I am getting error as

```
Input to reshape is a tensor with 4096 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 6400
```

Help me out here .

here is the model

```
UNITS = 128
IMG_SIZE = 240
BATCH_SIZE = 32
IMG_SHAPE = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
max_len = 50
VOCAB_SIZE = tokenizer.vocabulary_size()

def get_model():

    embdding_layer = Embedding(input_dim = VOCAB_SIZE, output_dim = UNITS, input_length = max_len, mask_zero = True)
    rnn = LSTM(UNITS, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)

    # image inputs
    image_input = Input(shape=IMG_SHAPE)
    print(image_input.shape)
    x = resnet_preprocessing(image_input)
    print('preprocess: ', x.shape)
    x = resnet(x)
    print('resnet: ',x.shape)

    x = Flatten()(x)
    print('Flatten:',x.shape)
    
    # x = layers.MaxPooling2D()(x)
    # print('pooling:',x.shape)

    x = Dense(UNITS)(x)
    print('dense: ',x.shape)

    # x = 
    x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, 50, 128))
    print('reshape: ',x.shape)
    print('')

    # text inputs
    text_input = Input(shape=(max_len,))
    print('text_input: ',text_input.shape)

    i = embdding_layer(text_input)
    print('embedding: ',i.shape)


    i, j, k = rnn(i)
    i, _, _ = rnn(i, initial_state=[j,k])
    print('i:', i.shape)

    #  attention between x and i
    l = Attention()([x, i])
    ll = Attention()([i, x])
    print('attentions: ',l.shape, ll.shape)
    
    #  concatnate x and i
    m = Concatenate()([l, ll ])
    print('concat attention: ',m.shape)
    
    m = Dense(VOCAB_SIZE)(m)
    print('dense out: ',m.shape)
    
    return keras.Model(inputs = [image_input, text_input], outputs = m)
```

output shapes

```
(None, 240, 240, 3)
preprocess:  (None, 240, 240, 3)
resnet:      (None, 8, 8, 2048)
Flatten:     (None, 131072)
dense:       (None, 128)
reshape:     (None, 50, 128)

text_input:     (None, 50)
embedding:      (None, 50, 128)
i:              (None, 50, 128)
attentions:     (None, 50, 128) (None, 50, 128)
concat attention:  (None, 50, 256)
dense out:      (None, 50, 19770)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of your dense layer is (None, 128), which for batch size of 32 is going to be 4096. The call to reshape says you want a tensor of (None, 50, 128) which is 6400, hence your error. Resnet preprocessing output according to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/resnet50/preprocess_input is 4d tensor (batch, three color channels), I'm guessing you want to do some convolution layers and pooling to downsample to (None, 50,128)? Also, having a max pooling layer (currently commented out) after a flatten is going to give you a single value, probably not what you want. I might suggest checking out the image classification example here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification.

hth

Answer (score 1):

for anyone who is looking for answer. This is the change i made.Thanks to [@brewmaster321](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/146483/brewmaster321) **UPVOTE his answer**

```
    # image inputs
    image_input = Input(shape=IMG_SHAPE)
    print(image_input.shape)

    x = resnet_preprocessing(image_input)
    print('preprocess: ', x.shape)
    x = resnet(x)
    print('resnet: ',x.shape)

    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)  # add a pooling layer\
    print('polling: ',x.shape)

    x = Dense(UNITS*max_len)(x)
    print('dense: ',x.shape) # now (32, 128*50) => (32, 6400(multiple of 6400)) as required

    x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, max_len, UNITS))
    print('reshape: ',x.shape)
    print('')
```

in Dense layer instead of just `Dense(UNITS)` now is `Dense(UNITS*max_len)`

removed `Flatten()` layer and added  `GlobalAveragePooling2D()`